# Moving Sprites along a path, while being affected by gravity

Tags: swift, skspritenode

I have a tower sprite with a SKShapeNode around it, and a monsterSprite. the Monster sprite is affected by gravity so i can detect contact with the towerSprite's SKShapeNode and the monsterSprite.

This is the TowerSprites SKShapeNode, and i did a similar thing for the monster(but with dynamic to yes):

```
self.towerRangeNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:100];
self.towerRangeNode.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
self.towerRangeNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagoryTower;
self.towerRangeNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
self.towerRangeNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagoryMonster | PhysicsCatagoryTower;
self.towerRangeNode.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
```

Then when i add the monster, i make it follow a path like this:

```
// creates path to monster to follow
CGMutablePathRef monsterPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(monsterPath, NULL, 0, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(monsterPath, NULL, 310, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(monsterPath, NULL, 310, -65);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(monsterPath, NULL, 12, -65);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(monsterPath, NULL, 12, -130);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(monsterPath, NULL, 350, -130);

SKAction *path = [SKAction followPath:monsterPath asOffset:YES orientToPath:NO duration:15];
[monster runAction:path];
```

So what i expect to happen is, the monster moves along the path, and if it collides with a tower's SkShapeNode, then i am notified, however the monster just falls off the screen, and doesn't follow the path, however if a skShapenode is in its falling path, it still detects it.

i would like it so the monster moves along the path, while being able to detect contact with the SkShapeNodes, and not just fall off the screen

thanks

Comment: set affectedByGravity to NO until the node collides, then turn it on and stop the path action